# Xcode: Why do I get a SIGABRT message using presentModalViewcontroller?

Tags: xcode, memory, presentmodalviewcontroller, sigabrt, automatic-ref-counting

I want to switch to another viewController. I have an UIButton on my view, the UIButton have an UILongPressGestureRecognizer by using this code:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *buttonLongPressRecognizer;
buttonLongPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LoadButtonSettings:)];

buttonLongPressRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
buttonLongPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;

[NewButton addGestureRecognizer:buttonLongPressRecognizer];
```

The action I use to switch viewControllers are this:

```
- (IBAction)LoadButtonSettings:(id)sender {

[ButtonSettingsViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

[self presentViewController:ButtonSettingsViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

The problem is that when I make a long press on the button my app crashes and gives me a SIGABRT error. Weirdly enough it only happens on my iPhone, not on the simulator.

I have also tried using

```
    [self presentModalViewController:ButtonSettingsViewController animated:YES];
```

and got the same problem. As I know SIGABRT means there's a memory issue, which I don't understand since Automatic Reference Counter is on.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ButtonSettingsViewController is the type of view controller you need to initialize it first:

```
- (IBAction)LoadButtonSettings:(id)sender {
    // init & alloc - Replace with your custom view controllers initialization method (if applicabale)
    ButtonSettingsViewController *viewController = [[ButtonSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"ButtonSettingsViewController" bundle:nil];

    [viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: yeah just realized that it was because i initialized it in ViewDidLoad... but thank you very much :D

Answer (score 2):

presentModalViewController:animated: requires a view controller object.  You're passing it a class (ButtonSettingsViewController).  First instantiate the view controller object:

```
ButtonSettingsViewController *viewControllerObject = [[ButtonSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ButtonSettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Then set the modalTransitionStyle property of that view controller object:

```
viewControllerObject.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

Then present it:

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewControllerObject animated:YES];
```

Comment: yeah just realized that it was because i initialized it in ViewDidLoad... but thank you very much :D